# How to properly use TypeLiteral in GinMapBinder?

Tags: gwt, gwt-gin

What im trying to do is to create map, where key will be class which extends my abstract class

```
GinMapBinder<Class<? extends Key>, Value> mapBinder = GinMapBinder
                .newMapBinder(binder(),
                        new TypeLiteral<Class<? extends Key>>() {
                        }, new TypeLiteral<Value>() {
                        });
```

but when i'm trying populate my map

```
mapBinder.addBinding(KeyImpl.class).to(Value.class);
```

i'm getting error:

```
 Error injecting @com.google.gwt.inject.client.multibindings.Internal() java.lang.Class<? extends my.test.gwt.gin.objects.Key>: Unable to create or inherit binding: No implementation bound   for '@com.google.gwt.inject.client.multibindings.Internal() java.lang.Class<? extendsmy.test.gwt.gin.objects.Key>' and an implicit binding cannot be created because the type is annotated.
  Path to required node:

 @com.google.gwt.inject.client.multibindings.Internal com.google.gwt.inject.client.multibindings.MapEntry<java.lang.Class<? extends my.test.gwt.gin.objects.Key>, my.test.gwt.gin.objects.Value> [com.google.gwt.inject.client.multibindings.BindingRecorder.bind(BindingRecorder.java:42)]
  -> com.google.gwt.inject.client.multibindings.MapEntry<java.lang.Class<? extends my.test.gwt.gin.objects.Key>, my.test.gwt.gin.objects.Value> [com.google.gwt.inject.client.multibindings.BindingRecorder.bind(BindingRecorder.java:42)]
  -> @com.google.gwt.inject.client.multibindings.Internal() java.lang.Class<? extends my.test.gwt.gin.objects.Key> [@Inject constructor of com.google.gwt.inject.client.multibindings.MapEntry<java.lang.Class<? extends my.test.gwt.gin.objects.Key>, my.test.gwt.gin.objects.Value>]
```

if i wont use `TypeLiteral`this will works, but i dont want class with raw type.
So i'll be glad if anyone can help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Curious how did you get the new TypeLiteral to work. I am using guice 3 and gin 2.1.1. TypeLiteral has a protected constructor. I can't figure out how to create a type literal with my generic class as you have done.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw If you initialize `TypeLiteral` as anonymous class, then you can access it constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved

I created provider for each Key

```
public class KeyImplProvider implements
        Provider<Class<KeyImpl>> {

    @Override
    public Class<KeyImpl> get() {
        return KeyImpl.class;
    }
}
```

and i'm adding elements to map by

```
mapBinder.addBinding(KeyImplProvider.class).to(Value.class);
```